# Pandas compare columns of list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have columns in my DataFrame storing `lists` and I would like to compare each element in the column with a `lists`.

All the methods I have tried fails:

```
df.list_col == ['3', '4']
df.list_col.isin([['3', '4']])
df.list_col.equals(['3', '4'])
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `in`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[2,4],[3,1]],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
        A  B
0  [1, 2]  4
1  [2, 4]  5
2  [3, 1]  6

print (df.A.apply(lambda x: 2 in x))
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Sorry if the question isnt clear and I haven't checked, but does this work with entire `lists`, as an example I have edited in the question